# std::vector<std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>>> compilation error in VS2017

Tags: c++, stdvector, unique-ptr, stdmap, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to compile code bellow:

```
std::vector<std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>>> processedIntervals;
std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>> empty_map{};
std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>>&& empty_map_ref = std::move(empty_map);
processedIntervals.emplace_back(empty_map_ref);
```

Error is :

```
Error C2280 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)':
attempting to reference a deleted function TTTT C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\xmemory0 840
```

The code is able to be compiled in VS2015 without errors. The same code for `std::pair` (instead of `std::map`) works well.

Why VS2017 cannot compile it?

Comment: You don't have to make `empty_map_ref`. Just move `empty_map` into processed intervals directly: http://cpp.sh/3elkk

Comment: You also can just call `emplace_back` with no arguments to add a an empty map directly to the back: https://ideone.com/9SyNNB

Comment: Have you try to compile it on VS2017? The code works well with GCC and VS2015. On VS2017 I see the same error:

std::vector<std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>>> processedIntervals;
std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>> empty_map{};
processedIntervals.emplace_back(std::move(empty_map));

Comment: emplace_back with no arguments throw the same compilation error

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour. It may be counter-intuitive, but `empty_map_ref`, despite its type, is an lvalue -- so you need to `move` it:

```
processedIntervals.emplace_back(std::move(empty_map_ref));
```

Comment: @MikeSmirnov well, in that case it's an implementation bug.

Comment: @MikeSmirnov see [this online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/831df4831b1e2e0c). If that doesn't compile on VS2017, you need to file a bug report.

Comment: I tend to submit bug, because GCC and VS2015 works well this the code. But, I want to check it with smart people :-)

Comment: @mike I find it more likely your code is in error, given that your example in the OP had such flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is wrong. Correct is

```
processedIntervals.emplace_back(std::move(empty_map_ref));
```

or directly

```
processedIntervals.emplace_back(std::move(empty_map));
```

or even

```
processedIntervals.emplace_back();
```

Since `empty_map_ref` is a named object, you must explicitly call `std::move` to ensure a rvalue reference. This is the same as for move constructors:

```
struct foo 
{
  std::unique_ptr<something> ptr;
  foo(std::unique_ptr<something>&&p) // constructor from rvalue ref
   : ptr(std::move(p))               // ptr(p) would fail exactly as in your code
};
```

Comment: Have you trued to compile my code on VS2017? 

    std::map<uint64_t, std::unique_ptr<double>>&& empty_map_ref = std::move(empty_map);
    processedIntervals.emplace_back(empty_map_ref);

is the same as 

processedIntervals.emplace_back(std::move(empty_map));

You may try to compile the code on your side.

Looks like issue not in the code (it can be compiled by VS2015).

Comment: No, it's not the same. I'm not on a windows machine and have never used the VS20XX compiler